# LoadRunner - Monitoring linux counters gives RPC error

Tags: networking, loadrunner

Linux distribution is Red Hat. I'm monitoring linux counters with the LoadRunner Controller's `System Resources Graphs - Unix Resources`. Monitoring is working properly and graphs are plotted in real time. But after a few minutes, errors are appearing:

```
Monitor name :UNIX Resources. Internal rpc error (error code:2). 
Machine: 31.2.2.63. Hint: Check that RPC on this machine is up and running.
Check that rstat daemon on this machine is up and running 
 (use rpcinfo utility for this verification). 
Details: RPC: RPC call failed.
RPC-TCP: recv()/recvfrom() failed.
RPC-TCP: Timeout reached. (entry point: Factory::CollectData).  
  [MsgId: MMSG-47197]
```

I logged on the Linux server and found `rstatd` is still running. Clearing the measurements in Controller's `Unix Resources` and adding them again, monitoring again started to work but after a few minutes, the same error occurred.

What might cause this error ? Is it due to network traffic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using SiteScope, which has been the preferred monitoring foundation for the collection of UNIX|Linux status since version 8.0 of LoadRunner.   Every Loadrunner license since version 8 has come with aa 500 Point SiteScope license in the box for this purpose.  More points are available upon request for test exclusive use of the instance.